# Change font for sections and subsections in toc and add dot line for chapters

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script, chapters, layout

I would like to alter my table of contents.

- The font of sections and subsections should be the same as the chapters (which is lmss).
- Chapters should have dotted lines too
- How do I remove the space between the toc-title and the header? It only appears on this page, it's fine elsewhere...

How would I do this? Is there some package to overwrite the defaults?
Thanks for any help :)

**source**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

%Packages
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} %Automatische Verweise mit \cref{} oder \cpageref{} auf \label{}. Bei englischer Arbeit muss "german" durch "english" ersetzt werden. 
\usepackage{float} %Unterdrückt das Fliessen eines Bildes wenn statt "h" "H" als float angegeben wird.
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[round, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} %Bibliografie
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%Konfigurationen

%Code-style
\import{Code/}{Codestyle}

%Bibliografie-Stil
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

%Kapitel-Abstand zu Kopfzeile verkleinern
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-0.2cm}}

%Kopfzeile und Fusszeile
\ihead*{\raisebox{-0.1\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics{example-image}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

%Listing-Namen überschreiben
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Quellcode}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellcodes}

%Glossar
\makeglossaries

%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman} %Wenn Arbeit auf Englisch geschrieben wird auf "english" setzen

%Titelseite

\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{2} %Seitennummerierung ab hier

\addchap{Abstract}
\addchap{Ehrlichkeitserklärung}

%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents{}

%Kapitel
\addchap{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
\addchap{Umsetzung}
\section{REST-API}

\end{document}
```

[image: my current toc layout]

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? It is missing in the example.

Comment: sorry, my bad. updated it!

Comment: The `tocloft` package provides all sorts of capabilities for controlling the appearance of the ToC (and LoF and Lot) but does not necessarily work well with the Koma classes.

Comment: @PeterWilson KOMA-Script classes load and use package `tocbasic` for ToC, LoF, LoT etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `\addchap`, so I guess you load a KOMA-Script class.

If the font of section and subsection entries in TOC should be sansserif:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\sffamily,
  pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{tocline}{section,subsection}
```

Chapter entries with dotted lines, use either class option `toc=chapterentrywithdots` or

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{tocline}{chapter}
```

Do not redefine `\chapterheadstartvskip` to adjust the space before chapter title. Use:

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.2cm,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% loads graphix
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

% load as last packages and do not load twice: 
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}

% adjust space before chapter title
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-.2cm,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}

% header and footer
\ihead*{\raisebox{-0.1\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

% tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\sffamily,
  pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{tocline}{section,subsection}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={8}]{example-image-a4-numbered}% dummy title page
\addchap{Abstract}
\addchap{Ehrlichkeitserklärung}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
\chapter{Umsetzung}
\section{Forschung}
\subsection{REST-API}

\blinddocument% dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional remarks:

I have removed the unrelated stuff.

Do not load packages twice and load packages `hyperref` and `cleveref` last (in this order).